# Get column names from table on which a particular index was created

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT name 
  FROM sys.COLUMNS 
 WHERE object_id = (
                    SELECT object_id 
                      FROM sys.objects 
                     WHERE name = 'Table_name'
                    ) 
   AND column_id = (
                    SELECT COLUMN_ID 
                      FROM sys.index_columns 
                     WHERE object_id = (
                                        SELECT object_id 
                                          FROM sys.objects 
                                         WHERE name = 'Table_name'
                                        )
                    )
```

I have written this query which provide the correct result, but I think it can be written in a more accurate way.

Can someone help me write this query in a more compact way?

Comment: @imankurpatel000 looks like sql server

Answer (score 2):

The "nicer" way is to use `JOIN` instead of correlated subqueries (which in my case don't work and throw an error: "subquery returned more than one row"):

```
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME = N'-your-table-name-here-';

SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    IndexName = ix.Name,
    ColumnName = c.name 
FROM 
    sys.indexes ix
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ix.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id AND ic.index_id = ix.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE 
    t.Name = @tableName
```

I also tend to try to use the *more focused* catalog views like `sys.tables` instead of relying on the "catch-all" `sys.objects` view

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col.name, ind.name
FROM sys.columns col
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON obj.object_id = col.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns incol ON incol.COLUMN_ID = col.column_id AND incol.object_id = obj.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind on ind.index_id = incol.index_id AND obj.object_id = ind.object_id
WHERE obj.name = 'Table_name'
```

Please try above query to get the column names. I have added one more join to `sys.indexes` table to get the index name in case you have multiple indexes for the table.
You can remove this join if not required. (As below)

```
SELECT col.name
FROM sys.index_columns incol INNER JOIN sys.columns col INNER JOIN sys.objects obj 
  ON obj.object_id = col.object_id 
  ON incol.COLUMN_ID = col.column_id AND incol.object_id = obj.object_id
WHERE obj.name = 'Table_name'
```